# Can't install packages on kubuntu

Tags: package-management, kubuntu

I just installed kubuntu 11.04 and first it downloaded and installed packages fine but after a few time it cant download the packages and it says:"connection has timed out" I already tried to unplug and plug my moden but it didnt work do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: seems like a network issue, can you surf the net with your browser?

Comment: Yes, I can surf the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) As A GENERAL fix, try connecting to the Internet and opening a Terminal then, try the following commands on at a time.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt-get -f install 
sudo apt-get --fix-missing install 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

Does it work? Does it stop? At what point does it stop and what error message does it give?

2) Try changing your Repositories to the quickest. (This can almost change day to day, so it needs to be watched.)

Go Synaptic Package Manager>Settings>Repositories>then, where it says "Download From" change to "Other"> Choose Select Best Server

Comment: Thanx,I selected best server and now it is working although the download speed is slower then what I used too I guass there are some problems with the usual server and I hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: You should try to find a mirror close to you. Many universities provide mirrors with really nice speeds. If you're not maxing out your internet or getting at least 1MB/s, you should find a better mirror.